# Debian pings LAN, can't access Internet

Tags: networking, debian

This is different than most of the other questions I've researched so far. My Debian server can access and be accessed on the local area network *only*. It cannot ping the outside world. It can ping the router, and can perform cached `nslookup`'s without a problem. When trying to do a `traceroute 8.8.8.8`, it cannot connect to anything.

If I do a `ping www.google.com`, I get the IP address, then all packets lost. I can ping my router, and my notebook from the system. I have tried restarting networking, and verifying the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. Name resolution is not an issue (as most others were), and this is not running a GUI. Currently, I am SSHing into it from my notebook. All other devices on my network can access the Internet. My Debian box is not an edge device, it's completely behind the router. What can I look for next?

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.4
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
        network 192.168.0.0

# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:6f:65:c4:44:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.4/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0

# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm a little upset right now...

Rebooted the router, and it got Internet access again. Guess I'll be updating the firmware on the router